# Were composite materials used on Soyuz and on Atlas launchers?

Tags: launch, launchpad, atlas-v, soyuz-launcher, composite-materials

I would like to know if composite materials were used on Soyuz and Atlas launchers but I can't find a lot on the web.
I also would like to know which components of other launchers are made of composites.

Can you show me some pics or links or just what you know about composites used in launchers and why are them used instead of other materials?
Do you know if and where composite materials are used in space launchpads?

Comment: For launchers that use composites, see http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13257/why-not-build-rockets-out-of-composite-materials

Comment: thank you but I just read it! 
I would like to know something about these two launchers! I'v just found their user manual but there are not a lot of pics and about soyuz there is not a lot about composites...
According to the manual only the fairing is in composite...

Comment: Not sure about launchers, but about all ablators I know of are composite materials.