# What's the thickness and weight of rocket tanks?

Tags: rockets, falcon-9, space-shuttle, atlas-v

I found it quite fascinating that the Shuttle External Tank was [as thin as 2.5mm](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5967/structural-composition-of-shuttle-liquid-fuel-tank-wall). That seems very thin for a structure over 40 meters tall and weighing as much as 760 000kg fueled.

I'm curious how this compares to other rockets. I know original Atlas had very thin "balloon" tanks — but how thin was it actually, and how much did it weigh? And what about other rockets in use, say Falcon 9 or Atlas V? Or something really big like Saturn V? How much thickness and weight you need in the tank to support the whole rocket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old school Atlas -- [0.1 to 0.4 inches](http://www.warrenmuseum.com/missiles/atlas-sm-65/) (2.5 to 10 mm) thick -- so, actually, similar to the metal portion of the shuttle ET.

Centaur upper stage tanks -- [0.014"--0.016"](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Boosters/Centaur/Centaur.htm) (0.36 to 0.41 mm) thick (!).

Saturn V's 1st stage tanks varied in thickness from [0.170"-0.254"](http://www.apollosaturn.com/ascom/s5flight/sec4.htm) (4.32 to 6.45 mm).

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Russell's answer, Falcon 9 apparently has [3/16''-thick walls](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/3yyx13/elon_on_twitter_falcon_9_back_in_the_hangar_at/cyhw6xn) (4.7mm). This is interesting, because it's more than Shuttle's ET and about as much as parts of S-IC, despite being a smaller rocket. Presumably this is for extra structural margins to make the stage survive multiple reuse.

Comment: The system won't let me suggest an edit for 1 character, so wanted to notify you that 4.7mm is 3/16''.

Comment: This [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/2012/05/the-rocket-factory-spacex-builds-them-from-top-to-bottom/) confirms wall thickness is "about 5 mm".

Comment: Falcon 9 carries thrust loss

Answer (score 1):

For ariane 5 the thickness is:

8mm for the solid boosters 
4mm for the cryogenic main stage.

However both have an additional thermal insulation layer. I couldn't find data for the booster [see comments], but it's 2cm for the cryogenic one.

Considering this data I wouldn't be surprised if the insulating layer is missing from the other answers.

PS: the fairing is 3cm thick.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5)

Comment: The insulating layer is not a structural component.

Comment: Of course, but it's misleading not to include it

Comment: AFAIK, the Ariane 5 boosters only have thermal insulation on the bottom end of the booster, on the inboard side which faces the first stage main engine.