# What is the thickness of the Falcon 9 - Electron outer casing (outer shell)?

Tags: spacex, rockets, rocketlab

What is the material of the Falcon 9 outer casing/electron shell, and what is the technical jargon for that specific part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you ask in the text (about the material) is answered [here](https://www.spacex.com/news/2013/03/26/falcon-9-structure) for the Falcon 9. You need to understand that the fuel and oxidiser tanks *are* the bulk of the structure, so the other wall of the tanks *is* the outer sheet of the stage for most of its length. They are made of an aluminium-lithium alloy. The domes at the ends of the tanks are plain aluminium and the faring which covers the payload is carbon fibre ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9_Full_Thrust)). The question about the thickness is answered [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/whats-the-thickness-and-weight-of-rocket-tanks) -- about 5mm (3/16 of an inch).

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. Any idea on how the tank made out of carbon composites as in Rocket labs(Electron)